# CSS Media Queries not working on mobile or tablet

Tags: responsive-design, media-queries, mobile-website

I have just uploaded my website onto a hosted server with 1&1. The problem I am having is I cannot seem to find out why the media query rules I have set are now not working / are ignorned.

I have tested on my iphone 5 but my website does not scale as it should. However  when I resize my browser (Google Chrome) on my desktop to tablet and mobile sizes it does scale correctly.

Is there any reason why when I resize my browser it works perfectly but when I test it on a mobile device it does not work / scale properly?

Just for extra info I am using wordpress and I include my css files in the right way through the functions.php file.

My website is www.jamieclague.com, please feel free to look at the source code.

Thanks for any help, much apprciated.

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php bloginfo('title'); ?>Jamie Clague - Freelance</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!----- CSS Stylesheet Link ------>
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
```

CSS - styles.php (snippet of the code)

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width:401px)
and (max-device-width:480px){
   .header{
     min-height:520px;
   }
   .banner-matter {
    top: 22%;
    width:100%;
   }
   .banner-matter p {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
   }

}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width:321px)
and (max-device-width:400px) {

  .banner-matter h2 {
    font-size: 27px;
  }
  .banner-matter p {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  a.more span {
    left: 30%;
  }

}

@media only screen
and (min-device-width:220px)
and (max-device-width:320px) {
    img.scroll {
       margin-top: -0.7em;
    }
    a.more {
       background-size: 92%;
       width: 180px;
       height: 64px;
       font-size: 1.15em;
    }
    .view {
      padding: 0.3em 0 0;
    }
    a.more span {
      left: 27%;
      top: 27%;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing max/min-device-width with max/min-width?

Comment: Yes I have, in fact that I had that to begin with. Actually when I use max/min-width it scales properly in the browswer but not on devices. But when I use max/min-device-width it does not scale properly on browser or on device... I am sure it is something small I must be missing?

Comment: Can you describe how it is not working? Using iphone 5 for example, 320px width. Is the styles using a different break point styles or not working at all?

Comment: I inspected your page on the iOS simulator and right away I see a `ul` (nav) has a set width of 700px+ which will for sure break your page. Please make sure to review your styling

Comment: Well from what I can see it is not using the media query styles what so ever for anything. For example, the main desktop / tablet navigation should be hidden when the width is 640px or less and a new dropdown nav me menu should be displayed instead. Again when I few this on my Iphone 5 it does not work/render correcly. Please feel free to resize your browser on my website to see how it should look and try it on mobile to see how it does not render properly

Comment: Are you 100% sure your css are included? I have a feeling the platform you are using includes different css files for actual mobile devices.

Comment: Yeah I am pretty sure as all of my CSS rules are in one stylesheet and the styles are clearly working for desktop so it should render the media query rules when it is appropriate. The ul you are talking about is the desktop navigation, the width of this is gradually decreased as the width of the page also decreased in size. For example to begin with the ul width is set to 950px but is then reset to 735px wide when the page/devices size decreases to 1135px and so on and so forth as it gets smaller

Comment: Ok, after closely inspection I see your css are there. The only suspicious thing I saw was `*/` at the end of the css file. I am not sure where your starting comment is for this closing comment but that could be your problem... all your css might be all commented out. Also `.nav:target a {` for mobile-nav.css is missing a font-size value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update

A couple of suggestions.

If you use web inspector you'll see a number of 404s, including
http://www.jamieclague.com/js/jquery.contentcarousel.js
http://www.jamieclague.com/js/jquery.mousewheel.js
http://www.jamieclague.com/wp-content/themes/portfolio/style.css
and a jQuery error from line 113
$ is not a function. (In '$(document)', '$' is undefined)

As a starting point it would be good to fix these.

Also, if I look in http://www.jamieclague.com/wp-content/themes/portfolio/css/style.css?ver=4.6, I'm not sure if you have a closing curly bracket for the statement that starts at line 1813

```
@media only screen and (max-width:993px){  
...
```

<strike>You need a viewport meta tag in the head of your document, without this the default behaviour for mobile devices will be to scale the page to fit your screen.</strike>

Something like the following will get you started.

```
<head>
...
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
...
</head>
```

Find out more about settings you can use: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your comment but as you can see from my orginal post I have the viewport meta tag included in my header.php file